# Trying to grab a big table with an azure Trigger Function and it keeps erroring out

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I've got a 20m+ row table that I'm trying to move from one azure sql database to another using a python Timer Trigger script (the goal of this is to be run daily and to grab more tables). This errors out when ran in the cloud, but I get no clarifying message on the error. My guess is that it's a memory issue, but I've upscaled my function app to the highest level it could go, and yet it still errors out. I'm running it locally, but it has yet to error out, will update if it does.

Here's the basics of my script:

```py
#engine creation
engine_azure = create_engine(conn_str,echo=True, fast_executemany=True)
conn = engine_azure.connect()

item = [['schema', 'table']]
sql_query = pd.read_sql_table(table_name=item[1], schema=item[0], con=conn)
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
df.to_sql(item[1], conn2, if_exists='append', index=True, method=None, chunksize=50000)
```

If there is any suggestion on why this might be happening/how to solve this, I'm all ears.